# поиск по sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite, search

В sqlite android храню текст (сохраняю его из edittext).
Сделал поиск (через like) по введенной фразе (в коде constraint), который в принципе работает:

```
String query = "select * from " + NoteEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                " where " +
               NoteEntry.COLUMN_1 + " like ?" +
                " or " +
                NoteEntry.COLUMN_2 + " like ?" +
                " ORDER By " + NoteEntry.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " DESC";

c = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{"%" + constraint.toString() + "%", "%" + constraint.toString() + "%"});
```

Проблема начинается тогда, когда встречается буква с ударением. То есть иногда из edittext в таблицу (поле TEXT) сохраняется текст с буквами под ударением (такой текст в edittext может попасть через copy/paste).
Так вот: когда поиск натыкается на букву под ударением, он ее в базе не видит. Все, что до буквы с ударением, он находит. Как только натыкается на букву с ударением, слово не находит. Если букву с ударением исправить на обычную, то находит все слово.

Понятно, что буква с ударением имеет другой код, чем просто буква.
Но хочется сделать, чтобы поиск находил слова и с буквами с ударением также, как и обычные.

Есть ли способ реализовать такой поиск? И как?

Comment: Перед поиском буквы с ударением менять на такие же, но без ударения. Вот нашлись некоторые идеи, как это сделать:  https://try2explore.com/questions/ru/10034522

Comment: За сравнение симвлов отвечает collation. В SQLite это [Collating Sequences](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#assigning_collating_sequences_from_sql). Изучайте.